# Is it possible to copy and paste the sum of the video files into the title of the snapshot file created from the video file?

Tags: powershell

Not long ago, I was wondering if there is a way to merge multiple text files into a single text file, so I came across PowerShell while searching Google. And I also found out that it can do various functions. So, I will ask if it is possible to implement the functions I really need.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I took a screenshot to make it easier to understand the intent of the question. When I download a new video file, I usually create a snapshot and copy and paste the sum information of the video file at the front of the extension name to organize and store. Creating a snapshot is not a difficult task, but I would like to know how to do it if it is possible to automate the subsequent work. As a result, is it possible to do batch work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows you how to construct a snapshot file name for each of the `.mp4` files in the current directory:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 | ForEach-Object {
  $snapshotFileName = '{0} - {1:N2}GB ({2} bytes).jpg' -f $_.BaseName, 
                                                          ($_.Length / 1gb), 
                                                          $_.Length
  # Display for diagnostic purposes.
  Write-Verbose -Verbose $snapshotFileName 

  # Use Rename-Item to rename a preexisting snapshot file.
}
```

See also:

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem)
- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object)
- `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)
- [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Verbose)
- [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item)